# Map type of member of tuple

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a mapped tuple that drills down to the type of a member:

```
export type Argument<T = unknown> = {
  value: T;
};

export type TypesOf<T extends Argument[]> = {[Index in keyof T]: T[Index]["value"]};
```

So, `TypesOf<[{value: number}, {value: string}]>` should yield `[number, string]`.

However, I get this error:

```
Type '"value"' cannot be used to index type 'T[Index]'.
```

EDIT:

Bonus question after applying @jcalz's solution:

```
const tuple = [{value: 1}, {value:"foo"}] as const;
type V = TypesOf<typeof tuple>;
```

I get error:

```
Type 'readonly [{ readonly value: 1; }, { readonly value: "foo"; }]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Argument<unknown>[]'.
  The type 'readonly [{ readonly value: 1; }, { readonly value: "foo"; }]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Argument<unknown>[]'.
```

Comment: Note that this question as stated doesn't spell out what the problem is: presumably it's the error I mention in my answer but it would be nice to know this for sure.

Comment: That was eaten... sorry, will add...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TypesOf` implementation you present works, in that `TypesOf<[{value: number}, {value: string}]>` does indeed evaluate to `[number, string]`.  [Mapped types on arrays an tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) result in arrays and tuples.

But there is an issue, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995) where the compiler does not realize that inside the mapped type *implementation* `{[I in keyof T]: ...T[I]...}` that `I` will only end up being the numeric-like indices.  It thinks that maybe `I` will be things like `"push"` and `"pop"`, and so `T[I]` cannot be assumed to be of type `Argument`:

```
export type TypesOf<T extends Argument[]> =
    { [I in keyof T]: T[I]["value"] };
// -----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '"value"' cannot be used to index type 'T[I]'.
```

Presumably this is why you asked this question in the first place.  The GitHub issue is listed as a bug, but it's been open for a long time and it's not clear if anything will happen here.

---

In cases like these I tend to use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to help convince the compiler that some type will be assignable to another.  If you have the type `T` that *you* know will be assignable to `U`, but the compiler does not, you can use `Extract<T, U>` in place of `T`.  When `T` is specified later, `Extract<T, U>` will evaluate to just `T` if you are right about the assignability.  And `Extract<T, U>` will be seen by the compiler to be assignable to both `T` and `U`.

In our case, we know `T[I]` will be assignable to `Argument` but the compiler doesn't.  So the following workaround using `Extract<T[I], Argument>` will suppress the compiler error without affecting the output of `TypesOf`:

```
export type TypesOf<T extends Argument[]> =
    { [I in keyof T]: Extract<T[I], Argument>["value"] }; // no error

type Z = TypesOf<[{ value: number }, { value: string }]>;
// type Z = [number, string]
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCUDmBXAtsAOxgB4AVOAXjmwIGsCIB3AgPkrgG8AoOXuANwCGAG2zAAXHFIBuLgF9ZXUJFgJkqAPIQwAZ1LqdGgGZk4oGIQAmO9FjyEYAbQC6bCjz4c4jgJJwAlgRwtMCIEEZSzpKkvs6OAERCosDxznAKXAD0mXAAtPkFhUX5bAB+5RWVFVk5+ihwAOSJImLxDXAAxoIEDPAARqjYOsCWCBABBJagavUNMT7ODQB0XErg0PBI9XXAhibk5lY2GDj4RC5uHrxevhPBoeGRkgCiIDBQgh0k884ANLanBwsBJJVppDJcLaoABa7B2e2Iji8oIkcAIeAGUHS-2RLVROnegUw6VcsmyMxh7Ec6NwmP+BKgROcXCAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added a BONUS QUESTION re using your solution with the typeof an actual tuple const.

Comment: Change your constraint to `T extends readonly Argument[]` instead of `T extends Argument[]`.  The former is more accepting than the latter (`Argument[]` is assignable to `readonly Argument[]` but not vice versa).  "Bonus questions" are kind of a no-no, though, since they are scope creep and you would probably be better off asking as a separate post (after searching for existing questions, of course).

Comment: Thanks, got it! I changed it to `export type TypesOf<T extends [] | [Typed, ...any]> = {[Index in keyof T]: TypeOf<Extract<T[Index], Typed>>};` to force passing tuples.